# Identify complex expression and replace

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, pattern-matching

I'm having trouble finding a way (if there is) to analyse an expression, identify a complex pattern in it and then replace it with another thing. I think it will be easier to explain my problem with the code.

I have these expressions for mx and my:

```
mz = MZ[x, y, t];
ang = ANG[t];
mzX = D[mz, x];
mzY = D[mz, y];
mod = Sqrt[(1 - mz^2)/(mzX^2 + mzY^2)];
mx = mod (Cos[ang] mzX + Sin[ang] mzY);
my = mod (-Sin[ang] mzX + Cos[ang] mzY);
```

I calculate the derivative of mx with respect to t, which yields a very complicated expression:

```
deriv = D[mx, t]
```

[image]

I want to identify the parts of it matching the definitions for mx and my. That may involve regrouping terms, distributing products, etc. And then, I want to replace those parts with "mx" and "my" to get an expression simpler to the eye. Note that FullSimplify does not achieve what I need.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thoughts. First, you may eliminate terms with sin and cos from `mx` and `my`:

```
scsols=Solve[({mx, my} /. {Sin[ANG[t]] -> s, Cos[ANG[t]] -> c}) == {Mx, 
My}, {c, s}] // FullSimplify//First
```

I introduced new `Mx` and `My`, they are labels for `mx` and `my` respectively. Next you make the same substitution of sin and cos into `deriv` and then substitute `scsols` into the result:

```
deriv /. {Sin[ANG[t]] -> s, Cos[ANG[t]] -> c}/.scsols//FullSimplify
```

This gives some expression including `Mx` (=mx) and `My` (=my) and other derivatives of `MZ` and `ANG`:

[image]

Maybe this is somehow "simpler to the eye.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at Experimental`OptimizeExpression.  So if you run ...

```
 Experimental`OptimizeExpression[D[mx, t], "OptimizationSymbol" -> z]
```

You get what essentially involves a program that finds subexpressions that occur frequently in your program and recursively builds a formula out of them.  It will not solve all of the issues you raise, but I suspect it will help.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it semi-manually:

```
MYoverMOD = (-Sin[ang] mzX + Cos[ang] mzY);
MXoverMOD = (Sin[ang] mzY + Cos[ang] mzX);
modSquared = (1 - mz^2)/(mzX^2 + mzY^2);
deriv = D[mx, t];
deriv /. {modSquared -> MOD^2, MXoverMOD -> MX/MOD};
Simplify[%, Assumptions -> MOD > 0];
% /. MYoverMOD -> MY/MOD
```

[image]

Here `MOD` $\equiv$ your `mod`, `MX` $\equiv$ your `mx`, and `MY` $\equiv$ your `my`.

If the subexpression appears several times, it can be a time-saver to use the simple substitution syntax.

For some reason I wasn't able to replace `MOD` directly (the square root symbol interferes), so I had to replace the expression under the square root with `MOD^2`, which gave `Sqrt[MOD^2`].  I then converted that to `MOD` using `Simplify`. I also had to do it in two steps to get the expression in a form that allowed `MY` to be substituted.